# Searching for a Blame

Tags: xcode, xcode10, blame

I'm trying to find some changes I made to some code within a project.  This is a team project having multiple contributors.

Is it possible to search for a particular blame within Xcode?

It would be easier for me to search via blame than to remember a particular file and line number.

Comment: Hey OP! Have you had a chance to look through my answer?

Comment: Yes.   Very helpful (particularly in a team environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Inside Xcode, open the left side menu and navigate to *Source Control Navigator*. You can also do this using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
2. In there, select the branch you're working on.
3. In the text box in the top right corner, start typing your version control username and press:
   *Author:{your-username}*

This will show you all commits *you* have pushed to the repository. You can select a commit to see which files were changed and access the respective files directly from there.